# How to restrict input numbers on a textfield between 1 to 9 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hello I am trying to implement a textfield for collecting a 4 character pin codes between 1 and 9

I have been able to achieve  restricting the input to 4 characters and just numbers

but I am having issues restricting the use of "0" in this textfield

please help

see my code below that I tried to make a restriction using min and max attributes

```
<input id="pin"  required name="pin"  oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
    type = "number"
    maxlength = "4" min="1" max="4"  placeholder="Pin Code">
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having with zeros? I can imagine a few possibilities, but that's a waste of time, when you can simply tell us.

Comment: do you only want to enter numbers from 1 to 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="pin"
       required
       name="pin"
       type="text" 
       maxlength="4" 
       onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 49 && event.charCode <= 57'    
       placeholder="Pin Code"
/>
```

@chap man simply use this code and you are good to go. It simply checks if the ASCII code of the input character lies in the range [49,57] which is the range of ASCII codes for numbers between 1 to 9

Answer (score 0):

See the border value change to `green` when the value has a length of 4 digits. The if statement checks with a regex for values only between 1-9 and for the length of 4 digits.

```js
var pinInputElement = document.querySelector('#pin');

pinInputElement.addEventListener('input', function(){

    if(/^[1-9]{4}$/.exec(this.value)) {
        this.classList.add('success');
    } else {
        this.classList.remove('success');
    }
});
```

```css
#pin {
    width: 100px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: orange;
}

#pin.success {
    border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="pin"  required name="pin" type="number"
    maxlength="4" min="1" max="4"  placeholder="Pin Code">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using regex

Html

```
<input id="pin" name="pin" placeholder="Pin Code">
```

jQuery

```
$('#pin').on('input', function(){
    var thisRegex = new RegExp("^[1-4]{4}$"); 

if(!thisRegex.test($(this).val()))
  {
      alert('fail');
  }
  else
      alert('Good');
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `replaceAll()` to replace all zeroes with an empty string.

Here is my full working example:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        function checkPin() {
            let pinInput = document.getElementById("pin");
            let value = pin.value;
            let maxLength = pin.maxLength;

            pinInput.value = value.replaceAll("0", "");

            if (value.length > maxLength) {
                pinInput.value = value.slice(0, maxLength);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="pin"  required name="pin"  oninput="checkPin()"
        type = "number"
        maxlength = "4" min="1" max="4"  placeholder="Pin Code">
</body>
</html>
```